# 'Highcharts' Labels/Items class missing that can be used to position labels anywhere in the chart area

Tags: highcharts

I have a case where i need to position a custom label on the chart. I know the below jQuery does the job but i need to do it from code behind. I saw the highchart codeplex (http://highcharts.codeplex.com/) to get the Labels/Items class but it doesnt exist. More over i written my own class as below but no luck.

Jquery

```
labels: { items : [{ html : labelme ,style : { left: '10px',top: '300px'}}] }
```

C# respective classes

```
Labels Class:

namespace Test.Core
```

{
    [Serializable]

```
public class Labels
{      

    public CSSObject style { get; set; }

    public Items items { get; set; }

    public Labels()
    {

    }
 }
```

Items Class:

```
namespace Test.Core
{
  [Serializable]
public class Items
{
     public CSSObject style { get; set; }

    public string html { get; set; }

    public Items()
    {

    }
}
}
```

while creating chart instance i do write below code:

```
chart = new LineChart
        {
Labels = new IMCharts.src.HighchartsNet.Labels.Labels
            {
                items = new Items
                {
                    html = "90 days mean change is 27%",
                    style = new CSSObject { top = "100px", left = "100px" }
                },
                style = new CSSObject { color = "#3E576F" }
            }

}
```

Please let me know if anything is wrong here or any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Purush